# Debug python Can't inspect variables in VS Code when code and python interpreter in the same folder .venv

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am new to using VS Code. I tried debugging "python code" in virtual environment and I have a problem with "inspect variables". When I specified the "python interpreter in the virtual environment folder.venv", which is inside folder of the project I am working on, it does not show up the debug tool bar and does not allow me to inspect variables. However, if I debug code residing outside the .venv folder, it works. The weird thing is that if I were to specify "python interpreter located insde the .venv folder of different project", it works. I have tried to set python.defaultInterpreterPath in settings.json and launch.json, but no luck. With Pycharm, I have no problem.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: don't put your source code in the `.venv` folder, you are allowed to delete `.venv` folder and reconstruct it based on requirements.txt. Do you put your source code in the system installed python folder (where python[.exe] is)

Comment: @Nick Nguyen Sorry, but it works well on my computer. Could you please provide more info, such as the screenshot of the file structure, the error prompts, etc.

Comment: Thanks riotV8, that's how I overcome problem, and I posted the question because I would like to know the cause in VS Code.  Steven-MSFT,  it does not show any errors.  As  rioV8 mentioned, I should put the source code outside the .venv folder as purpose of using virtual environment is that the codes only need the packages and scripts in .venv to run properly. Thanks everyone for taking your time to answer my questions.